# how to calculate mpeg-1 video size?

Tags: video, video-streaming, multimedia, mpeg, bitrate

I am newbie in studying multimedia, I want to calculate the size of each second for a mpeg-1 video, so I can deduce the required bandwidth to download the video as a stream (CBR bitrate) in real time, here is the video data:

- audio bitrate is 64 Kb/sec.
- NTSC video with mpeg-1, the NTSC    resolution is 352 x 288 in 16
  bpp.

I did a lot of searches and didn't find suitable answer :( , any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't find an answer because there really is no clean answer to this type of question.

First, you've not specified some key parameters for the creation of the video stream:

1. What is the frame rate? 30 frames/second, 25, 15, 1?
2. What is the key-frame interval?
3. What is the quality factor of the encoding?

The best you can do is make a few general assumptions:

30 fps and a compression ratio of 20:1

So 352 x 288 x 16 = 1622016 bits per frame

Then at 30 fps we get 48660480 bits per second.

Compressing 20:1 we get 2433024 bits per second of compressed video.

Add maybe 5% overhead for the container and packets: 1.05 * 2433024 = 2554675

Add in the audio rate 2554675 + 64000 = 2618675 bps or about 2.6 Mbps.

I think mpeg-1 was designed to fit into T1 channels which carry 1.544 Mbps, so my calculation from estimates is not far off.